# Will my program get more cpu time if it has more threads

Tags: multithreading, go, linux-kernel, threadpool

If currently kernel is scheduling 60 threads, they belong to 3 processes:

> A: 10 threads
>
> B: 20 threads
>
> C: 30 threads

And they are all doing computing (no disk IO)

Will C gets more stuff done than B, and B gets more stuff done than A?

It does not seem very fair to me. If I am a irresponsible programmer, I can just spawn more threads to eat more CPU resource.

How this relate to golang:
In go, typically the go scheduler has a thread pool of #of-CPU-cores threads. Why does this make sense if a process with more threads gets more stuff done?

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is an overloaded machine. It is only true that the process with more threads will get more work done if the CPU has no spare time.

Go was not designed to fight other processes for a greater share of an overloaded CPU. You are free to set `GOMAXPROCS` to any number you like if you desire to participate in such a fight.

In a more typical system where the total work is less than the total CPU time; a Go process with 8 threads and 30 goroutines will perform about equally to a process with 30 threads running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> It does not seem very fair to me. If I am a irresponsible programmer,
>   I can just spawn more threads to eat more CPU resource.

you can also allocate your entire free memory, cause OS-failure and hijack the network card. you can do sorts of things but then who will want to consume your softwares?

> How this relate to golang: In go, typically the go scheduler has a
>   thread pool of #of-CPU-cores threads. Why does this make sense if a
>   process with more threads gets more stuff done?

Golang goroutines are basically a threadpool. each goroutine is a thread-pool work item. many things can make your thread-pool thread block, like using synchronous IO, waiting on a (non-spin-lock) lock and manually sleeping or yielding. in these cases, which are very common, having more threads than CPU's usually increase the performance of your application.
Do note that not all IO is a disk IO. writing to your console is an IO operation, but it isn't really a "Disk IO".
another thing is that context switching may not consume a large portion of your CPU, and having more threads may not make your tasks-throughput degrade. so in this case having more threads means that your parallelism is higher, and yet you don't loose performance. this is somewhat common situation. context switching between threads these days is very cheap. having a bit more threads than your cores may not necessary kill your performance or degrade it in some way.

Comment: Thank you. Just want to clarify your goroutine `having more threads than CPU's usually increase the performance of your application` comment: I agree having more threads than CPU cores is better, but you does not need to increase `GOMAXPROXCS` just for that: "Goroutine that are blocked in I/O or other system calls or are calling non-GO functions, do need an OS thread, but GOMAXPROXCS need not account for them" from <The go programming language> page 281.

Comment: If it's like what I understand from your answer: CPU time is roughly even distributed on number of total CPU-intensive threads across OS. `GOMAXPROXCS` being set to number of cores does not make sense to me --- Using the number of cores as number of threads in thread pool would be meaningless.

Comment: If it is the case than maybe in GO there is no point of having more goroutine workers than CPU's.